# How to make an embed without a title or description Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make an embed for a commission but when I try making the embed's title and description "\u200b".. it is giving a space. What would I do in this situation?

[my try at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRNvh.png)

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA4AT.png)

embed:

```js
        const embed = {
            title: `\u200b`,
            description: `\u200b`,
            author: {icon_url: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/776700748494012427/9d95fa1d5e160032dff0b7f78953dc81.webp?size=128", name: "Camp Atoka's membercount"},
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'Members',
                    value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`,
                    inline: true
                },

                {
                    name: 'Goal',
                    value: `${goal}`,
                    inline: true
                },

                {
                    name: 'Left',
                    value: `${goal-message.guild.memberCount}`,
                    inline: true
                },
            ],
            thumbnail: {url: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/776700748494012427/9d95fa1d5e160032dff0b7f78953dc81.webp?size=128"}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't want those fields (title, description) to show up at all, couldn't you just remove them?
[Discord Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html) doesn't seem to explicit say anywhere that those are needed, there are only limitations to their sizes.

Comment: It says that the title is apparently needed. I can try though.

Comment: Okay, I have tried and it seemed to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, safe coding!